# Optimal Control - Finding input that minimizes a function

Tags: optimization, optimal-control

I am working on some optimal control problems but am having trouble getting started. The problem I am solving is

$$\dot{x}=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array} } \right]x+ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}0 \\ 1\end{array} } \right]u$$ with $x(0)=(1,0)$ and I have to find $u$ between $0$ and $1$ that minimizes $\int_0^1{u^2(t)dt} $ under the constraint $x(1)=(0,0)$.

I tried looking at examples online but they all seem different than mine because of the integral function. Correct me if I am wrong but is the goal to simply find a controller, u, such that it takes x from (1,0) to (0,0) while keeping the integral as small as possible? Is there a particular method used to solve these problems or is it all supposed to be intuitive? Thank you.

Comment: This is a linearly constrained least squares problem. What do you mean by 'supposed to be intuitive'? Are you taking a class or working from a text?

Comment: The answer is entirely analogous to the finite dimensional version of the problem, $\min\{ \|x\|^2 | Ax=b\}$ and involves adjoints.

Comment: It is a book problem and I am taking a class on it. We learned about something called the Hamiltonian which I think we apply to the problem but I am not exactly sure how. I will look into the topics you mentioned, thanks

Comment: I think the Hamiltonian is overkill here, but there may be context that your professor has supplied that I am not privvy to.

Comment: I see, thanks for your input. I have a question (might be a stupid one): does $\dot{x}$ in this case represent the state $x$ at the next time step or is it something else?

Comment: It is the derivative of the state vector.

Comment: You may need to review some background material.

Comment: Since your context is Hamiltonian you could look up Pontryagin's maximum (or minimum) principle.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen: Pontryagin's maximum principle is overkill here. Particularly if the OP is not sure what the dot in $\dot{x}$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general approach:

The system is $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$, where $(A,B)$ are cc.

Define $Lu = \int_0^1 e^{A(1-s)} B u(s) ds$. $L$ is linear and continuous. Since $(A,B)$
are cc. we see that $L$ is surjective.

The problem reduces to $\min \{ \|u\|^2 | Lu = b \}$, where $b=x(1)-x(0)$.

Since $L^2[0,1] = \ker L \oplus {\cal R} L^*$, we see that the minimum norm solution must be of the form $u = L^* y$ for
some $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Hence we need to solve
$L L^* y = b$, so get $y = (L L^*)^{-1} b$ and so the minimum norm solution is
$u = L^*(L L^*)^{-1} b$.

Note that since $L$ is surjective, $(L L^*)^{-1}$ is invertible.

A little work shows that $(L^*y)(t) = B^T e^{A^T(1-t)} y$.

You can simplify & short circuit the computations by diagonalising the system first.